# Exposing host devices during docker build

Tags: docker, docker-build, docker-buildkit

My docker build will be greatly facilitated by having my computer's GPU available to it during build time via the normal devices like /dev/kfd. How can I do this?

Here is what I have tried so far, after much research on the internet.

I am using docker buildx like this

```
docker buildx create --driver-opt image=moby/buildkit:master  \
                     --use --name insecure-builder \
                     --buildkitd-flags '--allow-insecure-entitlement security.insecure' \
                     --config ./buildkitd.toml
docker buildx use insecure-builder
docker buildx build --load --allow security.insecure . -t myimage
```

And the contents of the buildkitd.toml file is this:

```
# Define the builder to use for the build
builder = "docker"

# Define the context for the build
[context]
  # Use the current directory as the context
  local = ["."]
  # Map the /dev/kfd device to the container
  devices = ["/dev/kfd"]

# Define the steps for the build
[[steps]]
  # Use the Dockerfile in the context to build the image
  use = "./Dockerfile"
  # Tag the image with the specified name and tag
  image = "my-image:latest"
```

Inside the Dockerfile I have a line like this:

```
RUN --security=insecure  /load-deps.sh
```

Inside the script I test for the availability of /dev/kfd - and it's not there, then only device I can find is '/dev/pts'